# remove node links by python

Tags: python

Will someone tell me what is wrong and way this is not working

```
import bpy

for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    mat_node = mat.node_tree.nodes
    for node in mat_node:
        if node.name == "Principled BSDF":
            link = node.inputs[0].links[0]
            if link is not None:
                node_tree.links.remove(link)
```

---

It is indeed mess, but this is visual, of what i need.[image]

Answer (score 5):

If there are no links you will get indexerror, so I would rewrite your last three strings of code:

```
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    mat_node = mat.node_tree.nodes
    for node in mat_node:
        if node.name == "Principled BSDF":
            for link in node.inputs[0].links:
                mat.node_tree.links.remove(link)
```

Comment: It's not working. The console brings me error 'ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled' object has no attribute 'input'. Links are still there.I have three texture nodes and need to reach them by their links, then disconnect them and connect them in other inputs of Principled BSDF. How am i supposed to do that

Comment: Yes sorry, I have corrected my answer. If you have to create links between nodes you can write next code: bpy.data.materials['name of your material'].node_tree.links.new(soket_out, soket_in), where sockets are sokets of nodes which you whant to connect each other. Sockets you can get by next code: bpy.data.materials['name of your material'].node_tree.nodes['name of your node'].outputs(or inputs)[index of socket]

Comment: Testing via type `isinstance(node, bpy.types.ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled)`  will ensure you get all nodes of that type, in case the user has changed the name of the node.

Comment: It is not that easy, at least for me. I have to do that for large number of materials at once. All of the materials have same links. The problem is that, the texture node linked to certain input have different name.In one of the materials texture node name connected to specular is texnode.002 in other is texnode.011. That is way, have to to find them first.then delete the link and then link it back to roughness. I need to do that for two more inputs . There must be a way

Comment: I see nothing impossible in your words, but I think it worth to creat another question with clear describing of your problem.